# Self contained C routine to print string

Tags: c, assembly, operating-system, osdev

I would like to make a self contained C function that prints a string. This would be part of an operating system, so I can't use `stdio.h`. How would I make a function that prints the string I pass to it without using `stdio.h`? Would I have to write it in assembly?

Comment: What is your operating system?

Comment: have you look inside stdio.h?

Comment: @JuanPi OP said he can't use `stdio.h`.

Comment: @Rob - I think Juan's point was OP should take a look at how printf is coded if he wants to replicate it. Which is good advice.

Comment: Ah that's right, sorry.

Comment: If OP intends to write code that is *part* of the operating system, he will first have to lean how his operating system implements physical I/O, and how he can modify it.

Comment: @JuanPi Where exactly is `stdio.h`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will probably want to look at, or possibly just use, the source to the [stdio functions](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/cvsweb.cgi/src/lib/libc/stdio/) in the FreeBSD C library, which is BSD-licensed.

To actually produce output, you'll need at least some function that can write characters to your output device.  To do this, the stdio routines end up calling [write](http://www.unix.com/man-page/FreeBSD/2/write/), which performs a syscall into the kernel.

Comment: If OP wants it to be "part of the operating system", he can't reasonably use the operating system call that implements it.

Comment: @IraBaxter: Yes. That would be part that he would need to implement. I thought it was obvious that he wouldn't be calling the *BSD kernels.

Comment: You're basically talking about porting a C library to a hobby OS, which is a common thing to do, but quite a way down the road for the OP. He should probably start by read/writing directly to video memory.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you're doing this on an X86 PC, you'll need to read/write directly to video memory located at address `0xB8000`. For color monitors you need to specify an ASCII character byte and an attribute byte, which can indicate color. It is common to use macros when accessing this memory:

```
#define VIDEO_BASE_ADDR    0xB8000
#define VIDEO_ADDR(x,y)    (unsigned short *)(VIDEO_BASE_ADDR + 2 * ((y) * SCREEN_X_SIZE + (x)))
```

Then, you write your own IO routines around it. Below is a simple function I used to write from a screen buffer. I used this to help implement a crude scrolling ability.

```
void c_write_window(unsigned int x, unsigned int y, unsigned short c)
{
  if ((win_offset + y) >= BUFFER_ROWS) {
    int overlap = ((win_offset + y) - BUFFER_ROWS);
    *VIDEO_ADDR(x,y) = screen_buffer[overlap][x] = c;
  } else {
    *VIDEO_ADDR(x,y) = screen_buffer[win_offset + y][x] = c;
  }
}
```

To learn more about this, and other osdev topics, see http://wiki.osdev.org/Printing_To_Screen

Comment: This is only possible on systems / graphics cards that implement a "character-mapped" video memory; except for PC-Hardware, i.e. x86/x64-based machines with graphics cards that have a "VGA"-type BIOS (call this, if you like, a type of device driver), this isn't the case; the character-mapped functionality on PC-type graphics cards is done by the BIOS not the card hardware. To do this on, say, a RaspberryPI, you'd need to write a _Framebuffer Device Driver_. The use of VGA BIOS functionality is therefore not (much) different from the use of a console-type driver via `write()` system call.